# Angular 4 handle Location header in 201 response

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, redirect

I control both the front-end (Angular 4) and the backend (Node/Express) of the application.

Upon creating a "Widget", I want the user to be redirected to the WidgetDetails page.

What is the proper way to do this?

My REST request to create can return a `201` with a `Location` header, but how can my Angular code handle it correctly?

Comment: Can you please post the content of the Location header?

Comment: Like I said, I can make it whatever I want it to be.
The usual REST best practice is to set it to the URL of the resource that was created (`/api/widget/12345`).
But not sure if it matches Angular best practices.

Comment: Then you can use [router.navigateByUrl](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl), I have had something similar only I had to re-route to the list page once a 'Widget' was created.